# find columns that has only specific value in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 600 columns that some of them has only value =1 in some records ,this column represent alarm when get the value =1 otherwise value=null that we don't have alarm , I need to find this column in spark dataframe. I test this code but I can't find true output.

```
df.select([column for column in df.columns if df(column).isin(1)]).show()
```

[part of my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFpBk.png)

Comment: Why are you referencing two dfs? df and dfNotNull??

Comment: I correct this .

Answer (score 0):

```py
cols_to_filter = df.agg(*[F.max(F.col(c) == 1).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).collect()[0].asDict()

filtered_df = df[[c for c, b in cols_to_filter.items() if b]]
```

To explain

```py
# condition to check for in columns
cond = lambda c:F.col(c) == 1

# apply condition on all columns and max will return True if it's true at least once.
#This is then collected to a python dict to be programatically used in the format {col name: True/False}
cols_to_filter = df.agg(*[F.max(cond(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).collect()[0].asDict()

#now use that dict to filter the columns where the condition was True
filtered_df = df[[c for c, b in cols_to_filter.items() if b]]
```

Comment: when I run this code I have some columns with values more than 1 or less than one besides 1 , I need only exact value equal to 1 in a column or have null value @Topde

Comment: Just change the condition part of the code to whatever you want to check for e.g. `cond = lambda c:F.col(c) == 1`

Comment: In my Dataset , this part of code return all the columns.

Comment: I give up on you, good luck